# Restoring a DB issues

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to copy over the live database from one server and restore it on the dev server using SQL Server 2005. I have made a backup of the live db and copied the `.bak` file over to the dev server. I am trying to run this script and I keep getting errors:

```
ALTER DATABASE Portal SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

ALTER DATABASE Portal SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 
GO

RESTORE DATABASE Portal 
FROM DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\Portal.bak' 
WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10
GO

exec dbo.sp_fixusers
GO 

ALTER DATABASE Portal SET MULTI_USER
GO

ALTER DATABASE Portal SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

Errors:

> Msg 5052, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   ALTER DATABASE is not permitted while a database is in the Restoring state.
>   Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
>   Msg 5052, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   ALTER DATABASE is not permitted while a database is in the Restoring state.
>   Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
>       10 percent processed.
>       20 percent processed.
>       30 percent processed.
>       40 percent processed.
>       50 percent processed.
>       60 percent processed.
>       70 percent processed.
>       80 percent processed.
>       90 percent processed.
>       100 percent processed.
>   Processed 307768 pages for database 'Portal', file 'Portal_Data' on file 1.
>   Processed 127 pages for database 'Portal', file 'Portal_Log' on file 1.
>   RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 307895 pages in 130.538 seconds (19.322 MB/sec).
>   Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
>   Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.sp_fixusers'.

Comment: sp_fixusers is not one of the MS-supplied stored procedures found in master. If you google sp_fixusers you should find examples of what you are looking for, i.e. scripts that call the MS-supplied stored procedure sp_change_users_login.

Comment: Where does sp_fixusers live?  Just because you restore your database doesn't mean the database context will change to that database.  So it's looking for sp_fixusers in your current database (actually, because of the `sp_*` it is initially looking in `master`).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set your database to single-user mode or offline because your database is already in a RESTORING state.

Second, your script tries to use the stored procedure sp_fixusers. This is a [custom stored procedure to fix orphaned users](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=12615). If you need to use this stored procedure, you need to re-create it first, using the script in the link above. But it is possible that your databases uses a different version and it will be better if you use the sp_fixusers from your server/database.